# jQuery Javascript large scale application development

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, jquery-plugins

I have just been asked to describe the architecture for a large scale dashbaord style project that i will be working on.

I have bever worked on a application of this size and am a bit lost as to what to say.

Could i be pointed in the direction of any articles that may help me get started and hopefully finished.

I have gleaned the following information thus far but i am not really sure that it describes the architecture.

1) Use classes instead of seperate functions and each class or group should be contained within their own JS file

2) Prior to production there should be a compile step where said JS files are compiled and minified

3) Step2 does not have to contain all the files.  Jsut the common ones to start

4) Use a classloader to load classes, plugins etc when they are needed.  On research could jQuery's getScript function be used for this or even a jQuery plugin loader:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

http://www.unwrongest.com/projects/lazy/

Am feeling way out of my depth at the mo so any help would be massively appreciated.  Be honest, if the above is competely irrelevant then i guess i am in the wrong job :(

Comment: I always accept questions that have been answered.  Some i have asked in the past and have not been answered, mainly due to the way that i have asked them i think.

Comment: While there are a number of viewpoints on the issue, I personally strongly disagree with points 3 and 4 in your practices. Especially for someone at what I presume is your skill level, it would be much better just to load all your libraries at once. Realistically, your libraries won't be very large, and loading even large libraries like  Google APIs, jQuery, or its extensions takes a negligible amount of time, especially if you're going to keep the users one a single page anyway, AJAX style.

I can't really make any more specific recommendations unless you have specific questions, though.

Comment: agree with Steve above, minify, combine and compress the js as part of the build process/js handler

Answer (score 4):

Everything you need to know can be found here:

http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/

Create a library of loosely couple components that communicate through an application controller (e.g. event bus).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking at using ExtJS 4 for this. Its APIs and development methodology closely track what you would expect from .NET or Java for developing a large-scale desktop app.

Version four answers all four of your points. It has...

1) A system for defining Java/C#-like classes in Javascript that work almost exactly the way a Java or C# developer would expect.
2) Dynamic resource loading.
3) The ability to create a final product from the SDK which is a neat, compressed version which contains just what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you are to do this with pure Javascript, ensure you use some reference architecture in the job. What HDave pointed above is really good material. If you want a ready-made reference architecture as a project startup code, have a look at BoilerplateJS:

http://boilerplatejs.org

After some large-scale projects, I have compiled some of the learnings in to this framework. Look at the samples too. Some of the concerns you raised are already addressed in this codebase such as use of OO concepts, minification and optimizations, decoupled moduler design and many more too.